# MVC 3 File Download cuts the file name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building the Ajax Downloading of the file, but the returned file name is cut:

original filename:

```
Toksykologia - wyklady 2010.doc.pdf
```

the browser downloaded:

```
Toksykologia
```

The code

```
HttpResponseBase response = HttpContext.Response;
FileInfo TheFile = new FileInfo(filePath);
response.Clear();

cookie.Value = "success";

response.SetCookie(cookie);
response.Buffer = true;
response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + TheFile.Name);
response.Charset = "";
response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
response.WriteFile(TheFile.FullName);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I see that's caused by the blank space char, if I changed it to e.g. `_` it works fine